# Rails Render JSON of a has_many, through Association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json

I have 3 Models in my application
Artists, Albums and Songs

```
class Artist < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :albums
    has_many :songs, :through => :albums
end

class Albums < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :songs
    belongs_to :artist
end

class Albums < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :albums
end
```

How do render it as JSON wherein it returns an array of the Artists, each artist with a property 'Albums' wherein it is an array of the Albums for each artist and each album has a property Songs which is an array of songs for each album. Like this

```
[ {
    id: 1,
    name: Artist_Name,
    albums: [
        {
            id: 1,
            name: Album_Name,
            songs: [{
                id: 1,
                title: Song_Title,
                lyrics: Song_Lyrics
            }]
        }
    ]
}]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By rails convention the model names should be singular, secondly you last model name should be song.

To include nested associated resources inside Json Define you models like this:

```
class Artist < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :albums
  has_many :songs, :through => :albums

  def as_json(options={})
    super(include: { albums: { include:  :songs } })
  end
 end

 class Album < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :songs
   belongs_to :artist
 end

 class Song < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :album
 end
```

Now calling `.to_json` on your active record artist object will return you the nested albums and songs.

Or you can just call this `Artist.all.to_json(include: {albums: {include: :songs}})`

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you to use Jbuilder gem 
https://github.com/rails/jbuilder

Comment: if you want to use templating system for generating JSON like jBuilder. i would suggest [Rabl - Generate JSON and XML based APIs from any ruby object](https://github.com/nesquena/rabl)